# Scrolling not working in console of Chromecast debugger

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, javascript-debugger

Not sure whether or not to file a bug report on this. Basically, in the Chromecast debugger I can't scroll when using the console. Other things seem pretty broken too as there is also no scroll bar on the right side of the window. Am I the only one experiencing this? I haven't been able to scroll since Tuesday. The only thing I can do to navigate the page is hitting escape twice which brings me to the bottom of the page. Page-up/down, the arrow keys, and anything else does nothing.

My Chromecast's firmware is version 38401

Comment: Please open a bug on our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list) and include the operating system and the version of your chrome and of the cast extension. It would help to include a screenshot as well.

Comment: I have the same issue! So annoying.. I can't read all console logs because of this... useless debugger ever!

Comment: I've got the same bug, any update on this?